# Differentiate between required and optional flags in help message in Cobra

Tags: go, command-line-interface, go-cobra

I have created a command as follows:

```
cmd := &cobra.Command{
    Use:       "get",
    Short:     "Gets information",
    Long:      heredoc.Doc("Long description"),
    Example:   heredoc.Doc("example"),
    ValidArgs: []string{"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"},
    RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
        return myCustomExecutionFunc()
    },
    SilenceErrors: true,
}

cmd.PersistentFlags().StringVarP(arg1, "arg1", "", "", "Arg1 definition")
cmd.MarkPersistentFlagRequired("arg1")
cmd.PersistentFlags().StringVarP(arg2, "arg2", "", "", "Arg2 definition")
cmd.MarkPersistentFlagRequired("arg2")
cmd.PersistentFlags().StringVarP(arg3, "arg3", "", "", "Arg3 definition")
```

Now when run the command with `--help` I get the help message as follows.

```
Flags:
arg1  Arg1 definition
arg3  Arg3 definition
arg2  Arg2 definition
```

I want to group the flags as persistent (required) and non-persistent (not required) as follows

```
Required Flags:
arg1  Arg1 definition
arg2  Arg2 definition

Optional Flags:
arg3  Arg3 definition 

Or something like below

Flags:
arg1  Required Arg1 definition
arg2  Required Arg2 definition
arg3  Optional Arg3definition
```

I know I can use the `SetHelpTemplate()` function and set my own string that will be shown when help is instantiated, I'm wondering if there is a native cobra library or pflag way to define different categories of flags.

Comment: This feature is not ready yet. The status of [issue](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/1537) is open on cobra repo.

Comment: Thanks, will follow the issue.